# Complete Azure Deployments Take an Hour to Fail for Locked Resources

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I use Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Templates to deploy my Azure platform-as-a-service (PaaS) resources. I perform ARM Template deployments as "Complete" so resources not defined in the template are removed.

When I place an [Azure Resource Lock](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-lock-resources/) on an Microsoft SQL Server PaaS Database Azure resource and then perform a complete deployment with the database name changed it takes more than an hour for the deployment to fail.

The Resource Group deployment log events contain multiple HTTP code 409 errors,  "Cannot perform delete operation because following scope(s) are locked:", but the deployment retries for more than an hour before it fails with DeploymentFailedCleanUp.

I expected both the conflict error when deleting a resource and DeploymentFailedCleanup. How can I make the deployment fail quickly on 409 errors that occur during cleanup though?

Comment: I believe there is transient fault handling in built in ARM template based deployment.

Comment: you should probably raise a feedback item on this, nothing arm templates can do here